# How to fix AccessControl: account missing role on upgradable contract?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I'm using AccessControlUpgradeable and i get the following error when i try to trigger an adnin function on my deployed smart conntract (it work when tested localy with chai)

Fail with error
'AccessControl: account 'myaddress' is missing role 0x0000000000000000 ...'

```
function initialize(
    string memory _baseURIMetadata,
    bytes32 _merkleRoot,
) public initializer {
    __ERC721_init("XXX", "XXX");
    __ERC721Enumerable_init();

    __AccessControl_init();

    _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);        
    _grantRole(STARDUST_CONTRACTS_ROLE, _boxContract);

    baseURI = _baseURIMetadata;
    merkleRoot = _merkleRoot;
}
```

the function i try to trigger

```
function openPublic(bool _open) public onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE) {
    openForPublic = _open;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue while using truffle and [openzepeline upgradeable](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/truffle-upgrades) contracts.

An upgradeable contracts need to deployed using `deployProxy`.

make sure you use `deployProxy` to deploy the contrats, something like this:

```
const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');
const ContractArtifact = artifacts.require('ContractArtifact');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    const ContractProxy = await deployProxy(ContractArtifact, [], { deployer });
}
```